# Symfony2: Doctrine subscriber throws ContextErrorException - must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have such listener

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class MachineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
```

and method

```
/**
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
```

and Doctrine throw Exception

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Certificate\MachineBundle\Event\MachineSubscriber::preUpdate() must be
>   an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs,
>   instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs given,

Its strange becouse I use proper class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong namespace/class to typehint the `preUpdate()` function argument. The correct **[hierarchy](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.PreUpdateEventArgs.html)** is:

```
Doctrine\Common\EventArgs
|_ Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs
  |_ Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs
```

Typehint with ...

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventArgs;

public function preUpdate(EventArgs $args)
{
    // ...
```

... or ...

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    // ...
```

... or ...

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    // ...
```

... but **NOT** with:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
```